# Genealogy software for Windows RT

Tags: genealogy, windows-rt

I am looking for a genealogy package that will run on a Microsoft Surface using the ARM processor and the RT version of Windows 8/8.1.

Either free or paid for.

There are many packages for Windows; *Roots Magic* and *Family Tree Builder* to name but two.  They all seem to be for the x86 Windows only.

There are several web-based services for keeping a basic tree in the cloud; *Ancestry*, *Tribal Pages*, etc.  Which can, of course, be accessed from any browser.  However, none of these can hold the depth of information that most seasoned genealogists will have in their family trees.

I am after something that will maintain a database on the local machine, handling citations, photographs and reporting.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered hosting your genealogy database on your own website? There are genealogy extensions for the major CMSes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [BegatAll](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/c5533b80-b533-4b42-94ba-87164ed07c5b) described as: "A complete genealogy application. Create, Browse, Import, Export, Edit and Share your family tree. BegatAll provides a truly modern genealogy assistant with flowing, touchable tree views and efficient edit forms."

It is available for x86, x64 or ARM and is a Windows 8.1 app, probably working in Windows 8 as well. You can [download it from the Windows store](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-ca/app/begatall-genealogy-chronicles/c5533b80-b533-4b42-94ba-87164ed07c5b). It is quite inexpensive at just $5.